# Remove tap recogniser for modal UIView/Partial Curl

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, transition, modalviewcontroller

Is there a way to remove tap gesture recognition for partial curl transition?
Right now when user taps on curled view it curls back - dismisses.

I'm using it for quick sign up controller and I don't want users to accidentally tap and return without warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone trying to get Hitendra's answer to work you have to place your code after the `viewDidLoad`. I had success using the `viewDidAppear` function.

Here is a swift implementation also:

```
private func removePartialCurlTap() {
  if let gestures = self.view.gestureRecognizers as? [UIGestureRecognizer] {
    for gesture in gestures {
      self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
  }
}
```

Place it like so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  removePartialCurlTap()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the Partial Curl Transition it automatically adds the gestureRecognizer to dismiss on touch into the gestureRecognizers array of the next screen. You can easily see that adding a breakpoint to viewDidAppear() and use this code in the console as you can see in my print
 `po self.view.gestureRecognizers`

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPgnW.png)

Now add this code to the beginning of your viewDidAppear()
 `self.view.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()`

Also, if you want to return to previous screen using a button with curl down animation, you can easily use this code in the action method of your button
`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [yourview gestureRecognizers])
{
    if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UIGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        [yourview removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    }
}
```

please try above code.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I have 2 viewcontrollers: login and signup. I tried to put your code in both viewcontrollers replacing yourview with: self.view and login.view. Both had no effect.